# How do I get a readable table out of `svyby`?

Tags: r, survey

I want to end up with a three dimensional table that shows proportions (ie percentages) for each variable, split by two dichotomous variables. This is the code I've written that I think will produce a simplified version of what I'm looking for

```
> Testdesign <- svydesign(id = ~V021, strata= ~V022, weights = ~SAMPW, data= testydf)
> Tableone <- svyby( ~ V104 + V025  , ~ V013 + V502 , Testdesign , svyciprop,
 vartype="ci", method="beta", na.rm = TRUE
```

Then to have a readable table I understand it must be passed through `ftable`, but I don't understand the error. I saw [this explanation](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Help-with-ftable-svyby-td4741268.html) that also didn't clear things up for me unfortunately

```
> ftable(Tableone)

Error in rbind(matrix("", nrow = length(xcv), ncol = length(xrv)), 
charQuote(makeNames(xrv)),  : 
number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 3)
```

I could try to use the `Crosstab` function but I'm not sure how to integrate that with complex survey data (hence the `survey` choice to begin with)

`stargazer` looks promising but it doesn't seem to read the `svyby` output correctly so `ftable` still appears to be necessary?

EDIT: Here is a subset that can be used with the above code, sorry about the godawful chunk of text

```
 > testydf <- structure(list(V001 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7), V002 = c(124, 
166, 178, 178, 216, 2, 2, 214, 34, 149, 167, 221, 248, 62, 72, 
196, 6, 14, 51, 101, 188, 221, 129, 167, 186, 14, 18, 26, 97, 
111), V003 = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3), V004 = c(1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 
6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7), V005 = c(118748, 118748, 118748, 118748, 118748, 
1258174, 1258174, 1258174, 1931847, 1931847, 1931847, 1931847, 
1931847, 47672, 47672, 47672, 911631, 911631, 911631, 911631, 
911631, 911631, 2005349, 2005349, 2005349, 1060772, 1060772, 
1060772, 1060772, 1060772), V013 = c(3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 5, 1, 5, 
3, 2, 7, 2, 4, 2, 2, 7, 5, 3, 2, 5, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 7, 3, 
1), V106 = c(2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), SEX = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), V502 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), V025 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), V190A = c(4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
4, 4, 2, 1, 5, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3
), V130 = c(2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 5, 5, 1, 6, 6, 3, 2, 6, 3, 5, 3, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 6, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2), V131 = c(8, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 10, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
5, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8), V732 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), V836 = c(1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), V754CP = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
), V754DP = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), V754JP = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), V754WP = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), V756 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), V823 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0
), V824 = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), V761 = c(NA, 0, 0, NA, 
0, NA, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 
1, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA), V525 = c(2, 3, 1, 0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 
2, 2, 0, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1), V732.1 = c(99, 
99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 
99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99), V791 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), V791B = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), HIV02 = c(6918, 6928, 6882, 6883, 6919, 9523, 9521, 10340, 
446, 441, 445, 437, 436, 14071, 14065, 14066, 11443, 12111, 11328, 
11395, 11644, 11309, 14547, 14626, 15067, 12464, 12466, 12459, 
12462, 12468), HIV03 = structure(c(0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), labels = structure(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9), .Names = c("HIV negative", 
"HIV  positive", "HIV2 positive", "HIV1 & HIV2 positive", "ERROR : V-, W+, M+", 
"ERROR : V-, W+, M-", "ERROR : V-, W-, M+", "Indeterminate", 
"Inconclusive")), class = "labelled"), HIV05 = c(109959, 109959, 
109959, 109959, 109959, 1212890, 1212890, 1212890, 1856921, 1856921, 
1856921, 1856921, 1856921, 45717, 45717, 45717, 864793, 864793, 
864793, 864793, 864793, 864793, 1974222, 1974222, 1974222, 1066907, 
1066907, 1066907, 1066907, 1066907), HIV06 = structure(c(0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), labels = structure(c(0, 1), .Names = c("Negative", 
"Positive")), class = "labelled"), V104 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), TRANSEX = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), HIVKNOW = c(3, 
2, 2, 2, 4, 7, 7, 4, 5, 4, 7, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 6, 4, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 6, 4), HIVKCAT = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 
1), V021 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7), V022 = c(18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 13, 13, 13, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 11, 11, 11, 25, 25, 25, 
25, 25, 25, 9, 9, 9, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27), V023 = c(18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 13, 13, 13, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 11, 11, 11, 25, 25, 25, 
25, 25, 25, 9, 9, 9, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27), V024 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2), SAMPW = c(0.109959, 0.109959, 0.109959, 0.109959, 
0.109959, 1.21289, 1.21289, 1.21289, 1.856921, 1.856921, 1.856921, 
1.856921, 1.856921, 0.045717, 0.045717, 0.045717, 0.864793, 0.864793, 
0.864793, 0.864793, 0.864793, 0.864793, 1.974222, 1.974222, 1.974222, 
1.066907, 1.066907, 1.066907, 1.066907, 1.066907)), .Names = c("V001", 
"V002", "V003", "V004", "V005", "V013", "V106", "SEX", "V502", 
"V025", "V190A", "V130", "V131", "V732", "V836", "V754CP", "V754DP", 
"V754JP", "V754WP", "V756", "V823", "V824", "V761", "V525", "V732.1", 
"V791", "V791B", "HIV02", "HIV03", "HIV05", "HIV06", "V104", 
"TRANSEX", "HIVKNOW", "HIVKCAT", "V021", "V022", "V023", "V024", 
"SAMPW"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
"20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30"
), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried the factor update to no avail Many Thanks!

Comment: hi, please revise your question to include a minimal reproducible example.  `?svyby` has examples, thanks

Comment: @AnthonyDamico Does the edit constitute an acceptable reproducible example?  - Thank you

Comment: i'm still unclear what you're asking.  `V104` is all zeroes and you're just adding it to `V025`.  you will get better stackoverflow help if you use datasets pulled from the examples at the bottom of `?svyciprop` or `?svyby`

Comment: The `svyby` code seems to run fine its just that `ftable` can't load the output and I'm wondering why that could be. I assume it is a problem with what I'm feeding it through `svyby`. From everything I looked at it seemed like this was the right way to get one big table of the (weight and design adjusted)  population percentages for each variable by two other variables. Am I totally off base there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?svyciprop` states

*formula Model formula specifying a single binary variable*

setup

```
library(survey)
data(api)
dclus1<-svydesign(id=~dnum, fpc=~fpc, data=apiclus1)
```

correctly breaks

```
svyciprop( ~ I( api99 > 500 ) + I( api00 > 500 ) , dclus1 )
```

also correctly breaks

```
svyby( ~ I( api99 > 500 ) + I( api00 > 500 ) , ~ sch.wide , dclus1, svyciprop)
```

Comment: When you say "correctly breaks" do you mean "throws an error as expected?"  I got `Error in eval(family$initialize) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1` when I ran the example code

Comment: yep.  `svyciprop` is adding those columns, so sometimes it's a two.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is and it seems like I don't have the expertise/vocabulary yet to really communicate to anyone else what my problem is so I think I need to go a different route. Thank you for your time! And for asdfree :)

Comment: `~ V104 + V025` is not allowed.  unlike some other `library(survey)` functions, the first parameter of `svyciprop()` only expects a single column.  you are expecting both columns to be evaluated with `svyciprop()` separately, but the function is instead adding `(V104+V025)` before sending their sum through the `svyciprop()` which results in some cases outside of the allowed `[0,1]` range